# Javascript Move Video Stream to New Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, video-streaming

I am trying to move a video stream from one window to another.

The current window, has a simple div with a video stream in it.

```
<div id="divLocalVideo">
  <video id="localVideo" oncontextmenu="return false;" autoplay=""
         style="transform: scaleX(-1);"
         src="mediastream:http://192.168.1.100/ee1e6dfb-6d59-4030-b97c-e0a528fbe215">
  </video>
</div>
```

I tried moving the window, by doing the following:

```
var popup_window = window.open(url, popup_window_name, window_size);
popup_window.document.write($('#divLocalVideo'));
//popup_window.document.body.innerHTML = $('#divLocalVideo');
```

All that does is just add "[object Object]" to the new popup window.

Anyone know the correct way to move a video stream from the current window to another? I'm beginning to wonder if it is even possible. I could of course recreate the stream, but I was hoping to avoid asking for camera permissions again and dealing with the remote seeing the video close/open again.

I thought the best way would be to just open the popup window move the stream to it, and then when I close the stream to move the video stream back to the original window.

Thank you,

Daryl

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, you can fix it by doing the following:

```
popup_window.document.write($('#divLocalVideo').html());
```

So it is copying the html, which includes the stream.